# Kahler property and finite covering

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, kahler-manifolds, complex-manifolds, symplectic-topology

Let $(M,\omega)$ be a compact symplectic manifold and $\pi:\tilde M\to M$ a finite covering. Clearly $(\tilde M,\pi^*\omega)$ is a compact symplectic manifold. Suppose we know that $(\tilde M,\pi^*\omega)$ admits a compatible and integrable complex structure, is it necessarily true that $(M,\omega)$ also admits a compatible and integrable complex structure? If not, what is a good counterexample?